# How do you mute strings on higher frets when playing 3 notes per string patterns and switching between 2-3 strings?

Tags: technique

Let's say it's 1st position E natural minor with root note on 12th fret. I'm trying to play Buckethead-style licks. I'm doing my best to mute the strings when swapping between them, but I still get those unnecessary sounds once in a while. I mainly use my right hand's palm. Am I missing some important detail about muting strings?

Comment: "1st position" and "12th fret" do not compute.  Can you show tab or SMN for the tune you're playing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using your right hand, you might also want to use your left hand (especially for the higher strings). It might seem complicated at first but you'll get used to it.